# Scrapy XPath Incorrectly when there is Unicode in the page

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to get all divs that have category class.

Take a look at this page: www.postkhmer.com/ព័ត៌មានជាតិ

[image]

in scrapy shell: `scrapy shell 'www.postkhmer.com/ព័ត៌មានជាតិ'`

[image]

As you see I got only 2 elements back.

`scrapy fetch --nolog http://www.postkhmer.com/ព័ត៌មានជាតិ > page.html
scrapy shell ./page.html
response.xpath('//div[@class="category"]')`

Still got only 2 elements back. But when I open page.html in Sublime.

I got 15 matches:
[image]

The most interesting part is: when I remove the anchor link from the 2nd category:

[image]

and i run `response.xpath('//div[@class="category"]')` in the scrapy shell again, I got 3 elements:

[image]

I'm like what the hell!? Can someone help me to solve this problem please?

I've uploaded the file in [here](http://www.filedropper.com/scrapypage) incase you want to test locally.

Comment: This is a random guess. I have never worked with scrapy and with python. Perhaps the elements are not loaded when you request for them ? Can you put a wait to give some time for the page or all categories to be loaded ? Could it be possible that your code is only loading elements that are visible on screen ?

Comment: get this file http://www.filedropper.com/scrapypage and scrapy shell it to get xpath, then you'll know that it's the python and scrapy problem.

Comment: If you are sure that its a py and scrapy problem, then file a bug report.

Comment: Only 2 things can be happening here. Either the html is malformed and scrapy can't parse it or there's some trouble with scrapy and encoding. I think the first one is more likely. (this)[http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html] kind of gives it away. Since it works on Chrome what I would suggest is using selenium to make the browser fix the code and scrap the elements from there. I didn't test but maybe scrapy-splash can have the same effect.

Comment: hey thanks for the tip.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida: I did try selenium and it's working as expected! Thanks again.

Comment: hey @RafaelAlmeida: use your comment to answer this question, and I'll mark it as answer. Man, you're the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 2 things can be happening here. Either the html is malformed and scrapy can't parse it or there's some trouble with scrapy and encoding. I think the first one is more likely. http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html kind of gives it away.

Since it works on Chrome what I would suggest is using selenium to make the browser fix the code and scrap the elements from there. I didn't test but maybe scrapy-splash can have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

when you save the page into a local file `page.html`, you skip the http header that contains encoding information.
Later on, when you open this file , either with scrapy or sublime, they have no clue what was the original encoding of the document.

**Recommendation**: never used documents saved to a file for parsing.

Comment: can you prove it?